# How would I output the following from XML?

Tags: xml

I would like to show the following output from an XML document, but I am not sure how to do it. Can someone help please?

**Desired output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Integration>
   <ProtectionOrderStatus>
        <ProtectionOrderStatusCode>DELETED</ext:ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
    </ProtectionOrderStatus>
</Integration>
```

**XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Integration>
    <ProtectionOrder>
        <Deleted>true</Deleted>
        <ProtectionOrderNumber>12</ProtectionOrderNumber>
        <Statuses>
            <Status>
                <Current>true</Current>
                <Active>Yes</Active>
                <Date>03/16/2017</Date>
                <Type Word="SBJO">Signed By Judicial Officer</Type>
            </Status>
        </Statuses>
    </ProtectionOrder>
</Integration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what your processing language is.
So I just provide an XSLT-1.0 way of achieving this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/Integration">
      <Integration>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </Integration>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ProtectionOrder[Deleted = 'true']">
      <ProtectionOrderStatus>
        <ProtectionOrderStatusCode>DELETED</ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
      </ProtectionOrderStatus>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Integration>
    <ProtectionOrderStatus>
        <ProtectionOrderStatusCode>DELETED</ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
    </ProtectionOrderStatus>
</Integration>
```

This code generates an `ProtectionOrderStatus` element for each `<ProtectionOrder>` element of the source XML which has a `<Deleted>` child element with the `text()` value equal to `true`.